# How to detect distance between two taps in Android?

Tags: android, gesture-recognition

I have a custom gesture listener (inheriting from `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener`) created to detect double tap over a view.

The problem I'm having is that if I put the two fingers on the screen, that's detected as a double tap sometimes.

I want to consider it a double tap only if distance between the two taps is small. Right now I accidentally run the logic for double tap in random situations and that's a pain in the ass from user point of view

Comment: Why not just use a [GestureDetectorCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/GestureDetectorCompat.html)? It already has the logic for detecting double taps. See [Detecting Common Gestures](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html) for examples of how to use it.

Comment: @Ted Hopp: I'm already using a gesture detector, my problem is that I'm not happy with the double tap detection strategy. Not using `GestureDetectorCompat` but `GestureDetector`